# How to do an intersection of arrays of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I’m trying to do a function in php that try to make an intersection of an array of arrays. I have found `array_intersect($resultx,$resulty);` but it's working just for tables with one value. In my case I have arrays of arrays like that.

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Chris
        [id] => 1033
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Vins
        [id] => 1034
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Steve 
        [id] => 1035
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Henry 
        [id] => 1036
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jack 
        [id] => 1037
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => Paul
        [id] => 1038
    )
 )
```

To resume my problem I’m trying to make an intersection of lot of tables like the one i have mentioned. So any idea

examples tab1[[1,2,3],[2,3,1]] tab2[[1,2,3],[5,7,7] the result will be tab3[[1,2,3]] it is clear for you ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you actual inputs and what do you expect to get as your result?

Comment: and what would the other array look like?

Comment: Just google for "array_intersect_recursive", there are examples of this on the array_intersect page on php.net

Comment: my actual inputs some tables of tables like the one i mentioned in the body of the question and i expect a result table that contain the intersection of all the elements. examples `tab1[[1,2,3],[2,3,1]] tab2[[1,2,3],[5,7,7]` the result will be `tab3[[1,2,3]]` it is clear for you ?

Comment: @KANDROID OS, I have posted answer of your question,can you please look it once ? Let me know if you still have any issues !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KANDROID OS, Please check below example for intersection of arrays.

Suppose you have two array(s) like below:

```
$arr1 = array(
           array('name' => 'Chris','id' => '1111'),
           array('name' => 'Vins','id'  => '1112'),
           array('name' => 'Steve','id' => '1113'),
        );

$arr2 = array(
           array('name' => 'Chris','id' => '1111'),
           array('name' => 'dddd','id' => '2222'),
        );
```

You can use array_uintersect() to use a custom comparison function, like this:

```
$intersect = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, 'comparevalue');
print_r($intersect);

function comparevalue($val1, $val2)
{
   return strcmp($val1['id'], $val2['id']);
}
```

So Outcome of above is like below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Chris
            [id] => 1111
        )
)
```

Comment: @KANDROID OS, Glad ! I could help to resolve your issue.

Comment: I have tried to do it in the Framework Codeigniter its show an error he can't recognize the function comparevalue

Comment: @KANDROID OS, As I don't know you use codeigniter as a framework so I answered you in general manner,But for Codeingiter specific, you can store comparevalue function in helper file & you can auto-load that helper file. Hope It helps to resolve your issue.

Comment: yes it's wath i did i stored in a helper so many thanks body !

Answer (score 0):

You could recursively do it like this:

```
$arr1 = array(
          array('name' => 'Chris', 'id' => '1033'),
          array('name' => 'Vins',  'id' => '1034'),
          array('name' => 'Steve', 'id' => '1035'),
          array('name' => 'Henry', 'id' => '1036'),
          array('name' => 'Jack',  'id' => '1037'),
    );

$find   =  array(                              // Array for ANY search criteria, 
             array(1033),                      // name, id, etc.
             array('Vins')                     // (Each element needs to be an array)
          );

$match  =   array();                           // Define array for results    

for($i=0; $i < count($arr1); $i++){            // For every "name/id combo",
    for($j = 0; $j < count($find); $j++){      // go through every search criteria 

      $thisMatch = array_intersect( $arr1[$i], $find[$j]); // and check for a match

      if ($thisMatch){                         // If a match was found,
            $match[]    =   $arr1[$i];         // add it to the results array
            }
        }
    }

var_dump($match);
```

This will result in:

```
Array
  [0] => 
      Array (
          'name' => string 'Chris' 
          'id' => string '1033' 
           )
  [1] => 
      Array (
          'name' => string 'Vins' (length=4)
          'id' => string '1034' (length=4)
           )
```

You have to be careful though, with the example using the callback, trying to use the intersect for 'name' AND 'id' values WILL NOT return paired values as you might expect. It only needs to find one of the values, so if you try to search for a 'name' that corresponds to a different 'id', you will get both items back, even if that "combination" doesn't exist. It will do the same thing even if you use the keys in the search like this:

```
$find   =  array(  
              array('id' => 1033),                    
              array('name' => 'Vins') 
                );
```

I just noticed that issue so I thought I'd bring it up. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may need some sort of recursive aspect anyway, like I've shown.

Hope this helps :)